# List of Dynamic Links in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to take a posts tags and generate a comma-separated list of their links but can't seem to figure out how to accomplish it. Below is what I have, maybe I'm not using Jekyll's arrays correctly?

```
{% assign tag_array = [] %}
    {% for tag in post.tags %}
        {% assign tag_array = tag_array | push: '<a href="/tag/{{tag}}">{{tag}}</a>' %}
    {% endfor %}
{{ tag_array | join: ', ' }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Update

Iterate over the for loop, generating a comma if it is not the last iteration, and capture the output:

```
{% capture tagscommas %}
{% for tag in page.tags %}
    <a href="/tag/{{tag}}">{{tag}}</a>
    {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

{{tagscommas}}
```

If you want to avoid the output with line breaks just put all the code in one line until jekyll uses the new [{%-](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/whitespace) tag that doesn't generate blank lines.

If you don't mind having the output in a variable, just use the inner `for` loop to display the links directly as you traverse the tag array.

Comment: I'm already using a plugin to generate tag pages, that isn't my issue. My issue is building an array of dynamically generated strings and joining then with commas (,)

Comment: @alex-phillips I've updated the answer with the right code

Comment: Whitespace control `{%-` is liquid 4, which is still not used by jekyll see [gemspec](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/jekyll.gemspec#L37).

Comment: @DavidJacquel yes you are right, this is why I said "until Jekyll uses it".

Answer (score 1):

**Edited answer :**

Two problems here :

### Generating an empty array in jekyll

`{% assign tag_array = [] %}` does nothing.

`{{ tag_array | inspect }}` returns `nil`, and pushing (like `{% assign tag_array = tag_array | push: 'anything' %}`) in `nil` always returns `nil`.

In order to get an empty array you can :

1. set an `empty_array: []` in **_config.yml** and use it like this : `{% assign tag_array = site.empty_array %}`

**or**

2. create an array "on the fly" with : `{% assign tag_array = "" | split: "/" %}`

`{{ tag_array | inspect }}` now returns `[]`.

### String concatenation in jekyll

`{% assign link = <a href="/tag/{{tag}}">{{tag}}</a> %}` doesn't work in liquid. `{{ link | inspect }}` returns `nil`.

If you want to concatenate a string, you can use :

1. `prepend` or `append` [liquid filter](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters) like `{% assign link = '<a href="/tag/' | append: tag | append: '">' | append: tag | append: '</a>' %}`
2. `replace` filter like this : 
   `{% assign link_template = '<a href="/tag/%%placeholder%%">%%placeholder%%</a>' %}`
   `{% assign link = link_template | replace: "%%placeholder%%", tag %}`
3. `capture` tag like this : `{% capture link %}<a href="/tag/{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>{% endcapture %}`

And this now works :

```
{% assign tag_array = "" | split: "/" %}
{% for tag in post.tags %}
  {% capture link %}<a href="/tag/{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>{% endcapture %}
  {% assign tag_array = tag_array | push: link %}
{% endfor %}
{{ tag_array | join: ', ' }}
```

Comment: So this is how I'm currently doing it, iterating over the tags and printing out a link. But I want the links to be comma separated. How would I do that?

Comment: Sorry missed some errors in your code. Now it works.